# Заголовок меню в joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, php

Здравствуйте! Сайт на joomla 2.5.7, создал обычное меню, создал и разместил стандартный модуль меню на сайте, в настройках этого модуля ввёл заголовок "Меню" и настройку "Отображать заголовок", однако на сайте заголовок модуля не отобразился. Я полез в код шаблона /modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php и заодно заглянул в /templates/atomic/html/mod_menu/default.php , ни там ни там в коде вывода заголовка НЕТ! Т.е. код шаблона сразу начинается с формирования ul списка пунктов меню:

```
<!-- The class on the root UL tag was changed to match the Blueprint nav style -->
<ul class="joomla-nav<?php echo $params->get('class_sfx');?>"<?php
    $tag = '';
    if ($params->get('tag_id')!=NULL) {
        $tag = $params->get('tag_id').'';
        echo ' id="'.$tag.'"';
    }
?>>
и т.п. Подскажите как мне достать заголовок модуля меню, который я указываю в настройках модeля (http://myscreenshot.info/i/0001/604541358507916303667071429332.png) в административной части сайта? Заранее спасибо!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по скрину Ваше меню попадает в позицию "atomic-leftmenu".
Смотрим что происходит в файле: "корень-сайта/templates/название-шаблона/index.php"

Конкретно интересует строка вида:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="atomic-leftmenu" style="style-for-modules"/>
```

Обращаем внимание на style="**style-for-modules**" в твоём случае оно, конечно, будет называтся подругому - запоминай название стиля, оно сейчас пригодится :-)

Тепрь смотрим в этот файл: "корень-сайта/templates/название-шаблона/html/modules.php"
Ищем функцию которая будет заканчиватся на **style-for-modules**

Допустим функция называется: function modChrome_style-for-modules и есть у неё такие параметры ($module, $params, $attribs), так вот в теле функции заголовок модуля вызывается строкой:

```
echo $module->title;
```

Если нет такой строки - добавляй и будет тебе счастье, ну и заголовок модуля )

PS: Может быть другой вариант развития событий: У тебя строка

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="atomic-leftmenu"/>
```

не содержит атрибута style="style-for-modules", тогда смотрим в файле modules.php функцию у которой есть строка echo $module->title; и указываем в качестве атрибута style суфикс от этой функции (надеюсь понятное предложение получилось).

PS: PS: не гарантирую что данный способ сработает, но вроде как должно. Если что не понятно объяснил - спрашивай)